# Filtering Google Site Search results

Tags: javascript, xml, google-search-api

I know that Google Site Search provide a XML API (paid) to get a better control of results in our website.

But I have a website with a lot of articles stored in my database, so I'd like to filter my results (articles) by date, or by category for example. I don't know if it's possible with Google Site Search because is must interact with my database.

I'd like to know if it's possible and if so, how to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Site Search only provides you with the ability to search your visible web pages. It does not interact with directly with your database.

You'll need to either display all your database entries as web pages, or build a custom search engine if you don't want them to be displayed without passing through search first.

Comment: Thank you. I chose ElasticSearch.